# ggplot change of size and color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset for which I need to make a graph.

```
##Data
x <- c(10, 7.5, 5.5, 2.3, 3, 3.9, -2.5, -5, -9)
y <- c(3, 1.25, .75, -1.27, -.6, .88, -7.5, -5, -4)
z <- c("Good", "Good", "Good", "Average", "Average", "Average", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad")

##Dataframe
md <- data. Frame(x, y, z)

##Plotting
plot <- print(md %>% 
                ggplot(aes(x = x,
                           y = y))+
                geom_point(aes(shape = z))+
                geom_smooth(method = lm, se = F, color = "black")+
                labs(x = "X", y = "Y")+
                theme_minimal()+
                scale_shape_manual(values = c(24, 21, 25),
                                   breaks = c("Good", "Average", "Bad"))+
         
                theme(text = element_text(family = "Segoe UI"),
                      axis.line = element_line(size = .3, colour = "black", linetype = 1),
                      axis.ticks = element_line(size = .3, color="black"),
                      axis.ticks.length = unit(.1, "cm")))
```

Notice that as I use the `scale_shape_manual` I set three shapes that are analogous to the report I am preparing, hence changing them is not possible. However, what I need is:

1. fill those shapes with **black** color, and
2. increase the **size** of these shapes (same size for all but bigger)

I tried with `scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000", "#000000", "#000000"))` but it did not yield the result.

Please help me by correcting the issue.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: You have a typo preventing the code to run in the `md <- data. frame`. You need to remove the space and write `data.frame`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. not sure why it happened when I copied the code from RStudio to the HTML editor here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `fill = "black"` and `size = 3` arguments in the `geom_point()` outside of the `aes()` parameter.

Also, if you want to print a plot you don't have to assign it to a value then print it. You can just call it

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

##Data
x <- c(10, 7.5, 5.5, 2.3, 3, 3.9, -2.5, -5, -9)
y <- c(3, 1.25, .75, -1.27, -.6, .88, -7.5, -5, -4)
z <- c("Good", "Good", "Good", "Average", "Average", "Average", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad")

##Dataframe
md <- data.frame(x, y, z)

##Plotting
md %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = z), fill = "black", size = 3)+
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = F, color = "black")+
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y")+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(24, 21, 25),
                     breaks = c("Good", "Average", "Bad"))+
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Segoe UI"),
        axis.line = element_line(size = .3, colour = "black", linetype = 1),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = .3, color="black"),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(.1, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using `fill` and `size` inside the `aes` parameter.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, feel free to mark it as accepted :)